# How to access package level variable

Tags: python

Suppose i have package named src

```
    src
        - __init__.py
        - app.py
```

__init__.py

```
    ___version__ = '0.1.0'

    import os

    ENTRY_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    BASE_DIR = os path.dirname(ENTRY_DIR)

    DATA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data')
```

how can i access the variable DATA_DIR in app.py

I tried like this,

app.py

```
     from src import DATA_DIR

     print(DATA_DIR)
```

It didn't worked, i got an error.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

How can i acces the variable inside the app module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__init__.py` file is used to define how your package looks for an other one so you cannot do what you are trying to do since you are inside.

You can create a `cfg.py` like this :

```py
# cfg.py

import os

ENTRY_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
BASE_DIR = os path.dirname(ENTRY_DIR)
DATA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data')
```

So you can import `DATA_DIR` easily from `app.py` :

```py
# app.py

from cfg import DATA_DIR

print(DATA_DIR)
```

If you need to use the variables defined in `cfg.py` outside of your package you can modified the `__init__.py` :

```py
# __init__.py

___version__ = "0.1.0"

from .cfg import *
```

Comment: So the modules inised the package cannot access variables Inside __init__? Is there any reference to read about the __init__ file?

Comment: You can import it like any files with `import __init__` but it is not a good practice. You can read the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) and this [guide](https://climbtheladder.com/10-python-__init__-py-best-practices/) about good practices.

Answer (score -1):

it seems like you are referencing wrong path for that variable.

import the file in app.py

then you will be able to use variables from that file in same package.

use underscore with file name

import **init**

print(DATA_DIR)

Comment: It would be `import __init__` and it is not a good practice since this file is used to define the package for the outside, not the inside.